# Using type with emmbeded struct as function argument

Tags: go

Is it possible in golang to use type with embedded type as function argument?
In my example, I have `Dog`  and `Cat` types, both with embedded `Animal` struct.

I can call method `PrintAnimalNameWithReceiver` with the receiver of `*Animal` on both dog and cat objects.

I would like to be able to call also function `PrintAnimalName` by passing cat and dog variables.

Unfortunately this code doesn't compile with output:

```
./main.go:30:18: cannot use cat (variable of type *Cat) as type *Animal in argument to PrintAnimalName
./main.go:31:18: cannot use dog (variable of type *Dog) as type *Animal in argument to PrintAnimalName
```

Is it possible to change my code, so I can call `PrintAnimalName` with dog and cats variables?

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

type Animal struct {
    Name string
}

type Cat struct {
    Animal
}

type Dog struct {
    Animal
}

func main() {
    cat := &Cat{
        Animal{
            Name: "Cat1",
        },
    }

    dog := &Dog{
        Animal{
            Name: "Dog1",
        },
    }

    // Functions - compilations errors:
    // ./main.go:30:18: cannot use cat (variable of type *Cat) as type *Animal in argument to PrintAnimalName
    // ./main.go:31:18: cannot use dog (variable of type *Dog) as type *Animal in argument to PrintAnimalName

    PrintAnimalName(cat)
    PrintAnimalName(dog)

    //Methods - compiles without problems, prints:
    // Cat1
    // Dog1

    cat.PrintAnimalNameWithReceiver()
    dog.PrintAnimalNameWithReceiver()
}

func PrintAnimalName(animal *Animal) {
    fmt.Println(animal.Name)
}

func (animal *Animal) PrintAnimalNameWithReceiver() {
    fmt.Println(animal.Name)
}
```

Comment: No, not possible. However you could use an interface, implement it only once with Animal and then the Dog and Cat would both satisfy the interface if they embed Animal. https://go.dev/play/p/SIxu6-NJWkh

Comment: Thank you, your code solves my problem.